# Adding a digestion timer, in a predation model in Netlogo

Tags: timer, netlogo

I am building a coastal ecosystem where the starfish is the top predator and predates on all other 6 species.

I am trying to add a timer maybe 15 ticks whenever the predator feeds on a prey.

This is the code:

```
to move-starfish 
  ask starfish [ right random 360 
    forward starfish-speed set energy energy - 0.5 ]  
  ask starfish [predate]      
end


to predate 
  let prey0 one-of mussels-here
  if prey0 != nobody
  [ask prey0 [die] set energy energy + energy-gain-from-mussels  ] 

  let prey1 one-of thais-here
  if prey1 != nobody
  [ask prey1 [die] set energy energy + energy-gain-from-thais   ]

  let prey2 one-of limpets-here
  if prey2 != nobody
  [ask prey2 [die] set energy energy + energy-gain-from-limpets ]

  let prey3 one-of mitella-here
  if prey3 != nobody
  [ask prey3 [die] set energy energy + energy-gain-from-balanus ]

  let prey4 one-of balanus-here
  if prey4 != nobody
  [ask prey4 [die] set energy energy + energy-gain-from-balanus  ]

  let prey5 one-of chitons-here
  if prey5 != nobody
  [ask prey5 [die] set energy energy + energy-gain-from-chitons ]

  end
```

I just pasted the parts of the code that are of interest.

I would also, if possible, want to know if instead of energy-gain-from-(mussels) which is a slider I could get the energy the prey had at that time added to the predator.

This is for some University work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've called it a digestion timer, I gather you don't want the starfish to do anything for 15 ticks after it eats. If this is what you want, add a variable (say digestion) for the starfish and set it to 15 when it eats. In your go statement, `ask starfish with [digestion > 0] [set digestion digestion - 1]` and change your move starfish to `ask starfish with [digestion > 0] [...]`.

for future reference, ask a separate question for separate problems. But what you want is something like `set energy energy + [energy] of prey` before asking the prey to die.